# Entity Framework MIgrations working in a project with many developers

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project using EF migrations, I just need to confirm if we need to adjust anything or maybe a parameter in case more than one person is doing changes on the DB project. For example, yesterday a coworker was adding a column in a table and pushed the changes on the git project. I did get latest and today I need to do another db change in another table and when I create a new migration, the script is pushing the change my coworker did. Is there any wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you, but I understand that your colleague uploaded the column without generating the migration, then you downloaded his code, inserted another column and generated the migration, this migration has both changes... but this, for me, is correct :S

Comment: I'm using version 5

Comment: My colleague did the migration as well on his machine

Comment: I just drop the DB, pushed my colleague changes, then create my migration, push it and now works

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/teams